# Infinitesimal independence

Tags: random-variable, independence, mutual-information

Let's say we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. 
Is there a name for saying that $X$ and $Y$ are independent only for the values concentrated around a small interval around some $x_0$ and $y_0$ ? Like: 
\begin{equation}
\textrm{For all}~(x, y) \in [x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon] \times [x_1 - \epsilon, x_1 + \epsilon]: \\P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)\,P(Y=y)
\end{equation}
Or maybe we could say that some sort of local mutual information of $X$ and $Y$ in $x_0$ and $y_0$ is null ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited the question to use LaTeX formatting (https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). If you haven't already, you may wish to also check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: About the question itself: I think the definition of the property is currently somewhat unclear, e.g. is the property intended to be defined in the sense of "there is an $\epsilon$"?   Are the $P(X=x)$ etc. actually densities rather than probabilities?  Do you have an example where this holds?

Comment: If your interest is focused on this product of intervals (a "rectangle"), then you have effectively *truncated* the bivariate distribution, and your question concerns whether the truncated distribution is independent.  In light of that, there seems to be no need for special terminology.  Otherwise, if you are asking about the existence of such a rectangle, you will need to respond to @Juho's request for clarification so we can understand what the implicit quantifiers might be for $x_0,y_0,$ and $\epsilon.$

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thanks a lot for you answers. I guess my question was not clear to me either, I was just trying to know if there existed a more "local" definition of independence. Taking into account your remarks, maybe a more precise definition of the property I would look some terminology for would be something like:
$$\exists (x_0, y_0), \forall C >0, \exists \epsilon > 0, \forall (x, y) \in [x_0 - \epsilon; x_0 + \epsilon] \times  [y_0 - \epsilon; y_0 + \epsilon],  p(x, y) - p(x)p(y) < C$$
with p the probability density indeed

Comment: I don't have an example right now but I'll think about it. I guess then we could then describe joint distributions by saying that in some "areas" (surfaces of such points) or some "curves" (lines of such points) of the (x, y) planes, they are independent for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the $X$ and $Y$ rv's have a joint density $f(x,y)$, then you can compute the marginals of $X$ and $Y$, say $g(x), h(y)$ and compare the joint density to the independence density $g(x)h(y)$, for example via the likelihood ratio 
$$
   \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)h(y)}
$$
and plot that. In the following we have done this for the example of a joint Cauchy distribution:

[image: Likelihood ratio of joint Cauchy to product or marginals]

The `R` code used is:

```r
library(mvtnorm)
library(lattice)

mycplot <- function(df=1, ...) {
    x <- y <- seq(from=-3,  to=3,  length.out=101)
    grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
    grid$z <- exp( mvtnorm::dmvt(cbind(grid$x, grid$y), df=df, log=TRUE) -
                   dt(grid$x, df=df, log=TRUE) - dt(grid$y, df=df, log=TRUE))
    lattice::contourplot(z ~ x*y, data=grid, region=TRUE, ...)
}
```

Comment: I agree, this way we can see that when this graph has a value 1, the variables are independent indeed. Also, I think this function is in fact the pointwise mutual information (see the answer below https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392272/135346)
NB: There is a one half in your answer that I think is a typo:
`independence density ½g(x)h(y)`

Answer (score 3):

In fact I realized my definition with the small interval around points was weird: I realized there exist the Pointwise Mutual Information (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information), that will simply measure the independence between two random variables at a particular point x, y. I guess it was what I was looking for.
*Note:* actually the Pointwise mutual information is nothing else than a particular log likelihood ratio, which is described in @kjetil b halvorsen 's answer below https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/392272

Comment: Note that *pointwise mutual information* as defined in that Wikipedia article is nothing else than a particular log likelihood ratio! (which is **not** mentioneds there ...)

Comment: You are right, sorry for the late update, I have included a reference to your answer, thanks a lot